# Ported code having issues, can't figure out how this should work

Tags: sorting, lua, love2d

Okay, so I ported this bit of code from a javascript file to Lua. It's a solution to the Bin Packing problem. Basically, this is a given a target rectangle size "init(x,y)", and then is given a table with blocks to fill said rectangle, "fit(blocks)". <s>However when I run this I get the error "attempt to index local 'root' (a number value)". What is going wrong here?</s>

I <s>also</s> don't fully understand how this code is working, someone helped me along with the porting process. When I pass a table "blocks" into the fit function, is it adding the attributes of block.fit.x and block.fit.y?
Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Fixed the error by changing "." to ":" when calling a method.

```
--ported from https://github.com/jakesgordon/bin-packing

local _M = {}

mt = {
  init = function(t, x, y)       --takes in dimensions of target rect.
    t.root = { x = 0, y = 0, x = x, y = y }
  end,

  fit = function(t, blocks)     --passes table "blocks"
    local n, node, block
    for k, block in pairs(blocks) do
      if node == t.findNode(t.root, block.x, block.y) then
        block.fit = t.splitNode(node, block.x, block.y)
      end
    end
  end,

  findNode = function(t, root, x, y)
    if root.used then                 --if root.used then
      return t.findNode(root.right, x, y) or t.findNode(root.down, x, y)
      elseif (x <= root.x) and (y <= root.y) then
        return root
      else
        return nil
    end
  end,

  splitNode = function(t, node, x, y)
    node.used = true
    node.down = { x = node.x,   y = node.y + y, x = node.x,   y = node.y - y }
    node.right = { x = node.x + x, y = node.y,   x = node.x - x, y = y      }
    return node;
  end,
}

setmetatable(_M, mt)

-- Let's do the object-like magic
mt.__index = function(t, k)
  if nil ~= mt[k] then
    return mt[k]
  else
    return t[k]
  end
end

mt.__call = function(t, ...)
  local new_instance = {}
  setmetatable(new_instance, mt)
  new_instance:init(...)
  return new_instance
end

return _M
```

Comment: You need to use `:` when calling `t:findNode(...)`. javascript uses `obj.method` for both functions and object method. lua uses `obj.func` and `obj:method` (to pass the object as the first argument to the called function. http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.8

Comment: Thank you! Must have missed that. Still having problems with block.fit.x though.

Comment: Nothing assigns to `node` in the `fit` function. The original uses an assignment in the `if` and an implicit test on the assigned value as a truth value. lua can't do that so you need to split that into two statements.

Comment: Could you point me to that place? Line 63 on the original code? Here's the link for quick reference: https://github.com/jakesgordon/bin-packing/blob/master/js/packer.js

Comment: Correct, line 63 of the original code is `if (node = this.findNode(this.root, block.w, block.h))` with a single `=` for assignment. That statement is effectively `node = this.findNode(this.root, block.w, block.h); if (node)` which is, assuming compatible values for `node` the version you need for `lua` since lua assignments are statements and not expressions.

Comment: Thank you! It now sort of works!

Comment: look at `node.down = ` and `node.right = ` these lines are setting x and y twice instead of setting `w` and `h`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but here is how I would have ported the code over to Lua.

```
local Packer = {}

Packer.__index = Packer

function Packer:findNode (root, w, h)
  if root.used then
    return self:findNode(root.right, w, h) or self:findNode(root.down, w, h)
  elseif w <= root.w and h <= root.h then
    return root
  else
    return nil
  end
end

function Packer:fit (blocks)
  local node
  for _, block in pairs(blocks) do
    node = self:findNode(self.root, block.w, block.h)
    if node then
      block.fit = self:splitNode(node, block.w, block.h)
    end
  end
end

function Packer.init (w, h)
  local packer = {}
  packer.root = {x = 0, y = 0, w = w, h = h}
  return setmetatable(packer, Packer)
end

function Packer:splitNode (node, w, h)
  node.used = true
  node.down  = {x = node.x,     y = node.y + h, w = node.w,     h = node.h - h}
  node.right = {x = node.x + w, y = node.y,     w = node.w - w, h = h         }
  return node
end

return Packer
```

Just place it in a file like `packer.lua` and import it into your `main.lua` with `local Packer = require "packer"`